# Jquery/CGI : checkbox append/remove div

Tags: jquery, perl, checkbox, cgi

I'm trying to add and remove divs using checkboxes.
Some help for this script would be appreciable :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
                 if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
                        var nom = $(this).attr("value");
                        $('body').append($("<div id="+nom+">Switch "+nom+"</div>"));
                }else{
                        $("#" + nom).remove();
                }
        });
```

In the `else`, remove() does not work, there is a problem with the selector, don't know how to do with a variable, I searched on the web and did not find anything.
My second problem is for the append, it works, I can add a new div, but I'm using Perl/CGI, I would like to add a div made by : `my $switch1 = SwitchGUI->new("switch-rdc-7", 24, 2);` (that make an html reprensentation of a switch).

If someone could help me,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only give a value to the `nom` variable inside the "if-clause", that variable will always be undefined inside the "else-clause". So that means you select "#undefined", which doesn't exist, so nothing is removed.

I think it will work if you put the initialization (not only the definition, as that happens automatically) of your variable outside of the if/else construct like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        var nom = $(this).attr("value");
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $('body').append($("<div id="+nom+">Switch "+nom+"</div>"));
        } 
        else {
            $("#" + nom).remove();
        }
    });
```

As for your second problem:

I'm not familiar with that server side 'switch' thing you're talking about. But as your javascript is operating on the client, you just have to recreate what that SwitchGUI is creating. E.g. first create your GUI using that SwitchGUI thing, then look at the generated html code for that, and exactly recreate that in your javascript where you create your div now.

Comment: Thanks, it works. And what about my $switch1 = SwitchGUI->new("switch-rdc-7", 24, 2) ?? How can I do do add this instead of "<div id="+nom+">Switch "+nom+"</div>"

Answer (score 0):

First glance it looks like var nom should be declared outside the if block.

Comment: That doesn't matter, all variables inside a function are global to that function (even if they are inside if clauses). The "nom" variable will be undefined, when the else clause is hit though.

Comment: It should also be initialized outside of the if/else construct (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This should work:

```
$(function() {

    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        var nom = $(this).attr("value");

    if( $(this).is(':checked') )
            $('body').append($("<div id="+nom+">Switch "+nom+"</div>"));
    else
            $("#" + nom).remove();
    });
});
```